# Mouse cursor always get the wrong hwnd due to tab order - MFC Application

Tags: c++, mfc, groupbox, hwnd, mouse-cursor

I tried to get the window handle developed in MFC Application by using mouse cursor and print it out.

This is the code I used to get the window handle.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

        POINT pt;
        Sleep(5000);
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        SetCursorPos(pt.x,pt.y);
        Sleep(100);

        HWND hPointWnd = WindowFromPoint(pt);
        SendMessage(hPointWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON,MAKELONG(pt.x,pt.y));
        SendMessage(hPointWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELONG(pt.x,pt.y));

        char class_name[100];
        char title[100];
        GetClassNameA(hPointWnd,class_name, sizeof(class_name));
        GetWindowTextA(hPointWnd,title,sizeof(title));
        cout <<"Window name : "<<title<<endl;
        cout <<"Class name  : "<<class_name<<endl;
        cout <<"hwnd        : " <<hPointWnd<<endl<<endl;

        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;

}
```

I placed my mouse cursor on the button which inside a groupbox, then the result always show me the handle of groupbox instead of button. I found that the tab order is the reason that caused I can't get the handle of button

Is there any other ways or other windows function can be used to counter the tab order issues?

Any helps will be appreciate. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `RealChildWindowFromPoint` should solve this. However you'll need to provide a handle to parent window. Check the remarks section on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-realchildwindowfrompoint).

Comment: I would like to apply this on different dialog windows. But the parent windows have the class of #32770(Dialog) and some of the parent window has no name. It is hard to provide a handle of parent window for this function. I applied RealChildWindowFromPoint and I get the class in weird symbol and the handle is 00000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you need to call `WindowFromPoint` to get the most heavily nested window handle, then you need to call `RealChildWindowFromPoint` to get the "real" one and avoid groupboxes. But it also avoids static text so you need to continue looking for child windows using `ChildWindowFromPointEx` and `CWP_ALL` flag.

The implementation will be like this:

```
POINT pt;
GetCursorPos(&pt);
// Get the window from point
HWND hWnd = WindowFromPoint(pt);    
// map cursor position to window's client coordinates
MapWindowPoints(NULL, hWnd, &pt, 1); 

while (true)
{   
    // Now let's look for real child window
    HWND hWndChild = RealChildWindowFromPoint(hWnd, pt);
    if (hWndChild == hWnd)
    {
        // There's no "real" child but we still need to look
        // for Disabled/Transparent/Invisible windows
        hWndChild = ChildWindowFromPointEx(hWnd, pt, CWP_ALL); 
    }

    if (hWndChild == NULL || hWndChild == hWnd)
        break; // we haven't found any child, stop search

    // Continue search within child window
    MapWindowPoints(hWnd, hWndChild, &pt, 1);
    hWnd = hWndChild;
}

// At this point hWnd variable should contain the handle that you're looking for
```

Comment: It works fine for the tab order issues! But for the button/static text inside tab control, still cannot be detected. The result always have the same class (SysTabControl32) and hwnd. Is it the different case compare with tab order?

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I initially thought that your only issue is a groupbox. I'll edit my answer with more generic to get the window

Comment: Sorry to say that but the latest coding cannot get the window handle for both tab order and tab control. Might be the OR statement??

Comment: Hm... that's strange. When I tested that everything worked fine for me. What tab order of controls do you have?

Comment: I don't know the tab order of controls of the application that I used to test because it is a third party software. Can I know how you test the coding?

Comment: One of the way is by comparing the handle that I found with the handle that Spy++ shows. Another way is to call `GetWindowText` on handle that I found and compare it with the text I see.

Comment: I tried to create a dialog in MFC and test the latest coding. The content inside the tab control can be detected but the groupbox with tab order still wrong. I also tried the 1st version of coding, the content inside tab control also can be detected. So, I think that the reason might be the difference structure of tab control?? Because I can detect the content inside the dialog I created my own but cannot detect the 3rd party software tab control.

Comment: It's hard to say why. Can you use spy++ and check what's the hierarchy of windows that 3rd party app has?

Comment: The hierarchy of the dialog I created has 4 layers (#32770 -> SysTabControl32 -> #32770 -> Button) while the 3rd party apps has only 3 layers (#32770 -> #32770 -> Button). For the dialog I created myself, the tab control has the parent SysTabControl32 while the 3rd party apps, the tab control is not the child of SyTabControl32, it is the child of the main window (top parent). Sorry if my explanation is not clear.